# Get the body margin using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I defined the margin of my web page in a CSS file:

```
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-color: #000000;
    margin: 8px;
}
```

Using JavaScript/JQuery, how do I get the margin value? In this case the value '8'.

Comment: As per the downvote text: "This question does not show any research effort". It's trivially answerable.

Comment: He means the default value margin of body, not defined by stylesheet. You have 8px margin of body in clear html page, no css.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

that would be

```
$('body').css('margin');
```

Comment: But the value is not available on the ready event; I would like to get it there...

Answer (score 1):

get style..

```
$('body').css('margin');
```